# Sort Intervals in Joda-Time

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime, intervals

I have list of [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) [`Interval`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Interval.html) objects.

```
List<Interval> intervals = new ArrayList<Interval>();
```

How can I sort the intervals on the beginning Date of each interval. The intervals are not overlapping

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just create a `Comparator<Interval>` which compares by start times:

```
public class IntervalStartComparator implements Comparator<Interval> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Interval x, Interval y) {
        return x.getStart().compareTo(y.getStart());
    }
}
```

Then sort using that:

```
Collections.sort(intervals, new IntervalStartComparator());
```

Answer (score 0):

In your special case, collect the start instants using

```
interval.getStart()
```

in another list.  `DateTime` using the `Comparable` interface which makes the list sortable using `Collections.sort(..)`.

Comment: That will sort the start times, but it won't sort the *intervals* based on their start times.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Your solution is actually much better :-) - I must read the questions more carefully...